# Equal height script almost works

Tags: javascript, height, equals

I'm using this to equalize heights of two columns:

```
function equalheight(one, two) {
    if (document.getElementById(one)) {
        var lh = document.getElementById(one).offsetHeight;
        var rh = document.getElementById(two).offsetHeight;
        var nh = Math.max(lh, rh);
        document.getElementById(one).style.height = nh + "px";
        document.getElementById(two).style.height = nh + "px";
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    equalheight('primary', 'secondary');
}
```

... it works great, except that the height of the tallest column is increased further by 4-5px more, which is not required. Why wouldn't it calculate the height of the tallest column accurately?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it included any padding. Make sure you remove that, either by reading out the value of it and subtracting it, or by manually doing it using

```
var nh = Math.max(lh, rh) - 4;
```

or 5 or whatever is needed!

Comment: Nope, there no margin/padding applied to the elements.